# Error: [auth/operation-not-allowed] in authetication using firebase in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

> Error: [auth/operation-not-allowed] The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. [ The identity provider configuration is not found. ]

Having this error even if I have enabled the google sign-in provider in my firebase app. I have rechecked my SHA1 keys, but I still, have this error. I am trying to achieve authentication using firebase in react native android application.
Library used: `@react-native-firebase/auth`
Apparently, the same app(code) was working until I restarted the server. Please help! I have gone through relevant posts on all media but still haven't got the solution.

```
  async function onGoogleButtonPress() {
    // Get the users ID token
    const {idToken} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    // Create a Google credential with the token
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken);
    console.log(`CREDS ${googleCredential}`);
    console.log(googleCredential);

    try {
      auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Error 123 ${err}`);
    }
    // Sign-in the user with the credential
    return;
  }
```

`onGoogleButtonPress()` is the function I am using to sign in using google.

Comment: It sounds like you havent enabled GoogleSignIn in the  Firebase [console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=en)

Comment: I have enabled it! Still having the issue :'(